# How can I save German characters from Classic ASP to SQL Database

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am working with a classic asp application.

We have multilingual text in application e.g. German, italian etc. The texts are saved in database. When the text is displayed in the application the special characters (e.g. "ü, ä") are corrupted.

1. in web.config I have globalization tag with following configuration  but still the application text with special characters get corrupted.
2. I then added the  in my default.asp. Then the special characters are correctly visible in application.
   But here comes another issue while saving the data, the special characters got corrupted like this "wÃƒÂ¶chentliche"

Can you kindly guide me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure about classic asp? web.config is usually used by asp.net

Comment: @IłyaBursov `web.config` is an IIS concept not .Net it can be used by any hosted IIS web application including Classic ASP.

Comment: @IłyaBursov yes ,I am working in Classic asp application

Comment: It matters where you store the data. It also matters what the codepage and charset is you use on your pages. Can you expand your question with what codepage and charset you use and where you store the data.